# Something like vertex_id for Metal fragment shader, to identify fragment?

Tags: metal

Vertex shaders in Metal can use a `[[vertex_id]]` attribute on an integer argument, and  that argument will get values between 0 and the number of vertexes. Is there a similar thing for fragment shaders?

I want to write some debug info to a buffer, within the fragment shader, as shown below. Then in the CPU code, I would print the contents of the buffer, as a way to debug what is going on in the fragment shader.

```
struct VertexIn {
    float4 position [[attribute(0)]];
};

struct VertexOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
};

vertex VertexOut vertex_main(const VertexIn vertex_in [[stage_in]]) {
    VertexOut out;
    out.position = vertex_in.position;
    return out;
}

fragment float4
fragment_main(VertexOut vo [[stage_in]],
              uint fragment_id [[fragment_id]],   // <-- Hypothetical, doesn't actually work.
              device float4 *debug_out [[buffer(0)]],
              device uint *debug_out2 [[buffer(1)]])
{
    debug_out[fragment_id] = vo.position;
    debug_out2[fragment_id] = ...
    return float4(0, 1, clamp(vo.position.x/1000, 0.0, 1.0), 1);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK the closest thing in fragment shaders is 'position' which is the pixel coordinate of the pixel being written to. If you draw a quad you can convert to an index by adding `int(y) * width + int(x)`  ([See msl spec pg 100](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf))

Comment: Thanks. I'm using your suggestion and it works fine.